# What is the rationale for assuming that prediction values of a classifier are normally distributed per class?

Tags: classification, roc

A standard image to describe how to understand ROC curves is by showing the distribution of a model's predictions, grouped by real label. In this image, a histogram of predictions for class 'good' (in green) is compared against predictions for class 'bad' (in red). One sees that the model is able to differentiate between classes as both distributions have different parameters (mainly a different mean).

However I have not seen this in practice. Usually the prediction values are highly skewed. An almost perfect classifier would have something like exponential decay distributions, with a peak on 0 for one class, and a peak at 1 for the other.

In practice the distributions are seldom clear, far from normal, and there is high overlap.

Is there any reason to assume that predictions of a model for a given class are going to be normally distributed? is this purely for visualization purposes or is there any underlying theory supporting this?

[image]

Comment: What is the context of these plots? Are they representing actual data or only for explaining? The AUC value on the bottom right panel of the ROC curve seems totally off to me.

Comment: @Calimo nevermind the AUC, that is just an example image for explaining what a ROC curve represents, as we shift the threshold value on the x-axis of the left plot, we get different TPR and FPR points for the model which are plotted on the right. The left plot is pretty standard in this (I thought, just google ROC curves and you'll see this type of image often). What is more important, every time this image is used, the prediction distributions are Gaussian, which motivates my question.
 To answer your question: I assume this is artificial data, as I have never seen those distributions (?)

Comment: Never mind the gaussian, it is just an example distribution for explaining what a ROC curve represents, etc. They are nice and easy to use for demonstration, but ROC makes no parametric assumption.